# Determination of execution of mapper

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Whether help to define mapper  was executed and if it wasn't executed, for what reason it could occur. I wrote an output of the read ways from a database to the text file of local file system on which mapper is executed. Here I give a code

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;


public class ParallelIndexation {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();


        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            int CountComputers;
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countcomputers.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String result=br.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            input.close();
            fstream.close();
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;    
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch";
                String user = "postgres";
                String password = "valter89";
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                        st = con.createStatement();
                        rs = st.executeQuery("select path from tasks order by id");
                while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString(1)); };
                PrintWriter zzz = null;
                    try
                    {
                            zzz = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/readwaysfromdatabase.txt"));
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    zzz.println("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    zzz.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But despite it on one of the subordinate nodes the /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/readwaysfromdatabase.txt file wasn't created. Whether follows from here, what mapper wasn't executed at all? I bring also an output into the file of execution of the program

```
args[0]=/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input
13/04/22 14:00:53 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/04/22 14:00:53 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
13/04/22 14:00:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201304221331_0003
13/04/22 14:00:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/04/22 14:01:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 100%
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201304221331_0003
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 15
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=9079
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=7983
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=21536
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=16252928
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
```

I bring also an output into the file of successful execution of the program on one virtual machine

```
12/10/28 10:41:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/10/28 10:41:14 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/10/28 10:41:14 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/10/28 10:41:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
12/10/28 10:41:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/10/28 10:41:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
12/10/28 10:41:17 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: file:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt:0+156
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 199 bytes
12/10/28 10:41:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/10/28 10:41:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/10/28 10:41:19 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/10/28 10:41:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/10/28 10:41:19 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
12/10/28 10:41:19 INFO mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to file:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output
12/10/28 10:41:21 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
12/10/28 10:41:21 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 18
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=156
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=177
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=9573
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=73931
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=4
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=203
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=4
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=1
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=4
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=8
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=189
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=321527808
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=156
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=4
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=98
12/10/28 10:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
```

@ChrisWhite I ran programm with the help of command

```
./hadoop jar /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/ParallelIndexation.jar org.myorg.ParallelIndexation /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output -D mapred.map.tasks=1 1> resultofexecute.txt 2&>1
```

I have in a cluster 4 nodes, among which one principal, one for secondarynamenode and 2 subordinates.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it.

Comment: The DataInputStream is redundant, but this bad example is copied 30x per month on stack overflow.  It pains me because it is wrong and has always been wrong and sometimes leads to bugs which were entirely avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

How many map tasks were scheduled for your job, and how big is your cluster? If say your job only ran 4 map tasks and a cluster with 32 nodes, then chances are that 28/32 nodes won't have any output (as no map tasks ran on those nodes).

You can see information as to how many map tasks make up your job, and where those jobs were scheduled to run via the Job Tracker web UI.

Oddly, your first run dump doesn't show any map jobs launched, just reduce tasks:

```
13/04/22 14:01:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
```

And there are also no counters for the map input / output records so something odd is up with how you're running this job - can you share the full command line you are using to launch your job and possible the driver code that configures and runs the job?

Comment: I ran programm with the help of command

    ./hadoop jar /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/ParallelIndexation.jar org.myorg.ParallelIndexation /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output -D mapred.map.tasks=1 1> resultofexecute.txt 2&>1

@ChrisWhite

Comment: I have in a cluster 4 nodes, among which one principal, one for secondarynamenode and 2 subordinates.